# How to change the customizer´s sidebar width?

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer

I want to increase the width of the expanded sidebar in the WP customizer.

The relevant customizer markup:

```
<div class="wp-full-overlay expanded preview-desktop">
  <form id="customize-controls" class="wrap wp-full-overlay-sidebar">
    <div id="customize-preview" class="wp-full-overlay-main">
```

The CSS:

```
.wp-full-overlay.expanded {
    margin-left: 300px;
}

.wp-full-overlay-sidebar {
    width: 300px;
}
.wp-full-overlay-main {
    right: auto;
    width: 100%;
```

I tried it with this CSS in my childtheme´s style.css

```
.wp-full-overlay.expanded {
    margin-left: 500px !important;
}
#customize-controls.wp-full-overlay-sidebar {
    width: 500px !important;
}
```

and these lines of JS in an enqueued scripts.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
$(".wp-full-overlay.expanded").css("marginLeft", "500px");
$(".wp-full-overlay-sidebar").css("width", "500px");
});
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enqueue a style sheet to your admin or dashboard with `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook like below-

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'the_dramatist_admin_styles' );
function the_dramatist_admin_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'admin-css-override', get_template_directory_uri() . '/your-admin-css-file.css', false );
}
```

And put your admin `css` code there. As your code above the inside of `your-admin-css-file.css` will look kinda like-

```
.wp-full-overlay.expanded {
    margin-left: 500px !important;
}
#customize-controls.wp-full-overlay-sidebar {
    width: 500px !important;
}
```

And it'll work.

Comment: This Plugin here did the job for me:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-css-mu/

Answer (score 0):

### Making the customize sidebar a higher percentage of the screen

The answer by CodeMascot works, but I figured I'd also submit a percentage-based answer, since from what I can tell the current system is mainly maxed-out by percentage of the screen, and it seems like an elegant way to go so that you are less likely to have  problems if you use a smaller screen.

```
/*Wider customizer sidebar based on percentage*/
/*It will fall back to min-width: 300px*/
.wp-full-overlay-sidebar {
    width: 22%;
}
/*Wider margin on preview to make space for sidebar (match theme)*/
.wp-full-overlay.expanded {
    margin-left: 22%;
}

/*Below a certain size we revert to 300px because it's the min-width*/
/*Calculate this number as 300/% i.e. 300/.22=1363*/
@media (max-width: 1363px) {
    .wp-full-overlay.expanded {
        margin-left: 300px;
    }
}
```

For me this solved my problem after I tuned the percentage to reflect the widest size the site I'm working on takes up on the screen I'm using. For editing CSS I would have made it even higher if I was working on a site with a smaller max width.

### For bonus points, here's how to enqueue the CSS file if it lives in a plugin rather than the theme

(if you have it in your theme, see CodeMascot's answer above):

```php
function jer_admin_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'admin-css-override', plugins_url( "jer-admin.css", __FILE__ ) , false );
} 
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'jer_admin_styles' );
```